# Java recursion multiple

Tags: java, recursion, void

I was trying to understand how height is calculated in BST. So I wrote a program to see the steps but I get this error. Please help correct the code.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.Math;

class recurme {

    public void rec(int k) {
        int i = 0;
        int count = 0;
        count++;
        System.out.println(count + "  ..." + k);
        i = Math.max(rec(k - 1), rec(k - 1));
        System.out.println(i);
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int n = 10;
        recurme obj = new recurme();
        obj.rec(10);

    }
}
```

Error:

> void type not allowed here.

Comment: `rec` returns `void`: you can't call `Math.max` on void.

Comment: Hint: what type of expressions are you passing to `Math.max`?

Comment: Even if your `rec` method did return a value, it still doesn't make sense: why would you call `Math.max` with the *same* argument twice? Do you understand what you are trying to program?

Answer (score 0):

```
i = Math.max(rec(k - 1), rec(k - 1));
```

The culprit is the above statement.

Look at the documentation to see what Math.max expects as inputs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max(int,%20int)

Look at what your rec method gives as output.

```
public void rec(int k)
```

This should help you understand what is missing.

Comment: sorry! didnt understand. Please tell the answer. Thank u

Comment: public int height(BSTNode node)
 {
     if (node == null)
     {
        return -1;
     }
     else
     {
         
         return 1 +Math.max(height(node.left),height(node.right));

Comment: Your code is calling Math.max with void. Something like this: Math.max(void, void);